# Unable to download file from aws

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am very new to aws ec2. I am able to connect to my aws instance through ssh. However, I am getting error when trying to use `scp` command to download files from the server to my local machine or upload from local machine to the server.

here is how I use the command to download a file from aws to my local machine:

`scp -i C:/users.../MyFile.pem ubuntu@ec2xxxxxx.amazonaws.com: /aws_filepath/xxx`

I get error:

> Warning: Indentity file MyFile.pem not accessible:no such file or
>   directory Permission denied (publickey). cp: omitting directory
>   '/aws_filepath/xxx'

I am not sure where do I specify the file name of the file I want to download?
Could you please check my command and see what is i am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a windows machine? And are you using Windows CMD line?

Comment: @error2007s I am on windows machine, connecting through putty to aws and run on ubuntu.

Comment: When using putty you must first convert your pem file to a putty key file. Refer to the "Converting Your Private Key Using PuTTYgen" section at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the error is in the path. Use the command in this format. Remove `c:` also make sure you have the pem file in that path.

```
scp -i /users.../MyFile.pem ubuntu@ec2xxxxxx.amazonaws.com: /aws_filepath/xxx
```

Comment: This is how I entered and it did not work. I checked MyFile.pem is on my desktop. 
`scp -i /Users/xxxx/Desktop/MyFile.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com: /var/www/myfile.php`

Comment: Add it under Users directory and then check